# fontcolor plugin doesn't work

Tags: redactor

I added [fontcolor plugin](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/plugins/) on the last version of `RedactorJS` (9.1.1). It doesn't work. I can't add a plunker / jsFiddle because `RedactorJS` need a licence but I give my conf file:

```
<script src="redactor/redactor.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/fontcolor/fontcolor.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('#redactor').redactor({
    buttons: [
        'bold',
        'italic',
        'underline',
        'fontcolor',
        'formatting',
        'image',
        'link',
        'unorderedlist',
        'orderedlist',
        'alignment',
        '|',
        'html'
    ]
});
});
</script>
<textarea id="redactor" name="content">
    <h2>Hello and Welcome</h2>
    <p>...</p>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FIX this that:

```
$('#redactor').redactor({
    plugins: ['fontcolor'],
    buttons: [
        'bold',
        'italic',
        'underline',
        'formatting',
        'image',
        'link',
        'unorderedlist',
        'orderedlist',
        'alignment',
        '|',
        'html'
    ]
});
```

Comment: But how do you position the fontcolor button? This adds it on to the end which isn't ideal. Adding 'fontcolor' to the list of buttons doesn't do anything.